# How to retain a UIView controller (ARC)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-management

These 4 files are relevant to this post:

The FirstViewController has a button (not on the nav bar, a separate button), when it is pressed, the page should curl up to present FilterViewController.

FirstViewController.h

```
- (IBAction)searchOptions:(id)sender;
```

FirstViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)searchOptions:(id)sender {
    FilterViewController *ctrl = [[FilterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FilterViewController" bundle:nil];
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:ctrl.view duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ctrl animated:NO];
}
```

On FilterViewController it has some UI stuff, you press a button, it saves the UI stuff and then the page curls back down to show the FirstViewController.

FilterViewController.h:

```
- (IBAction)backToMap:(id)sender;
```

FilterViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)backToMap:(id)sender {
    FirstViewController *ctrl = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
        [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:ctrl.view duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown completion:nil];

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The issue here is with the retention of UIView. How can I retain the UIView?

When I click the button on FirstViewController the animation works and the page is presented. However on FilterViewController when I click the button it crashes to the debugger with the error:

**EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,address=0x8)**

In the output console it says: `(lldb)`

After the page curl up I have a stepper, when I click the stepper I get the same error in the debugger.

UPDATE: I have tracked the memory location error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye0Rm.png

Thanks.

Comment: "The issue here is with the retention of UIView" : that's **really** vague.. Try precising your question. Is your app crashing ? Are you recieving a warning ? What's expected ? What's actualy happening ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the vagueness - updated, hopefully the bottom part explains better

Answer (score 3):

One thing I notice is that you're pushing a view controller, then pushing another view controller with the syntax "back". This may be the issue: A nav stack is a stack. If you start with view 0, push view 1, if you want to get back to view 0 you "pop" view 1 as opposed to pushing view 0 again.

So in:

```
- (IBAction)backToMap:(id)sender {
       FirstViewController *ctrl = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
        [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:ctrl.view duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown completion:nil];

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hi Isaac, thanks for the comment. I am still new to obj-c so these terms dont come as easy yet. I have updated my question, but its memory management. When I did the 'zombie' thing it said that in output I get `(lldb)`

Comment: @JoshBoothe I've updated the answer. I believe your issue is that you are pushing a view controller when you should be popping.

Comment: thanks for updating. It says: `No visible @interface for 'UINavigationController declares the selector 'popViewController:animated'` not too sure what that means

Comment: @JoshBoothe, the correct method name is popViewControllerAnimated:. That error is telling you that there is no such method named popViewController:animated:.

Comment: @rdelmar I've updated the answer with the correct method name, my mistake.

Comment: __A nav stack is a stack__! You don't say... :D

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I am still getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using this code - interestingly, the problem may not be this code in question. After the page curl up I have a stepper, when I click the stepper I get the same error in the debugger

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you try to make animation between view controllers with UIView's transition method.

According to documentation:

```
fromView
   The starting view for the transition. By default, this view is removed 
from its superview as part of the transition.
toView
   The ending view for the transition. By default, this view is added 
to the superview of fromView as part of the transition.
```

So, when you call this method, your ViewController's view replaced by another view with animation, and after on stack placed next ViewController without animation, so it's seems like all right (but your first controller's view already replaced).

But when you try to return some error behavior occurs - you replace view of controller, that will be removed.

So, i want to say, that i must be done more carefully, there several different approaches to make custom transition between viewControllers.

For example, you can watch next solution (it's similar to yours) - http://www.vigorouscoding.com/2011/05/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/

or

https://gist.github.com/jeksys/1507490